# Multi-Criteria Look-up to pull optimal value

Tags: excel

I have a table `Table1` with Part #s and the length being purchased. I also have another table `Table2` with all the part #s and the different lengths that these parts are available in (to be cut from).

PartA could be stocked in 20ft, 22ft, or 40ft pieces. I'm wondering if there is a way for excel to look at each part in `Table1` and compare to the lengths for that part in `Table2` and based on the length it was sold at tell me which length it should be cut from (the optimal length with the least waste).

For Example: A customer purchased PartA and want's it in 42ft pieces and we stock 40ft, 44ft, & 48ft pieces. So I would pick the 44ft piece to make the order. I could then have another order for that same PartA for 20ft pieces, in this case I would select the 40ft. This is a very small representation of the possible sizes so it would have to evaluate each one individually based on their stock sizes. Not all parts are stocked in 3 different sizes, some are stocked in 1 size others more.

Table1:
[image]

Table2:
[image]

*There are typically many pieces in an order, for instance if I had an order for 12ft pieces I would use the 48ft to make 4 12ft pieces.

Comment: Possibly doable, but we would need some sample data to suggest an appropriate solution.

Comment: Index Match more than likely will address this, but we need to see more about your data before we can do any formulas.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57959761/edit) instead of adding information in comments. Please also provide sample data.

Comment: Okay, where do I upload the sample data? All I see are links and picture uploads.

Comment: You can just add it to your question in tabular format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited my answer using your exemplary dataset and additional requirement -

```
=INDEX($F$2:$F$8,SUMPRODUCT(MATCH(SMALL(IF(($E$2:$E$8=A2)*($F$2:$F$8>=B2),MOD($F$2:$F$8,B2),10^100),1),IF(($E$2:$E$8=A2)*($F$2:$F$8>=B2),MOD($F$2:$F$8,B2)),0)))
```

Note that this is an array function so needs to be entered using `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`.

Results:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Justyna MK this works for pulling the next biggest size but it doesn't pull the "optimal" size, say in the case I have a 12ft order and I stock 20ft and 48ft, I would have them use the 48ft pieces because there would be less/no waste.

Comment: @osugirl7 thanks for the comment - could you please explain the logic? I'd understand that in case of a 12ft order, 20ft would give you a waste of 8ft, while 48ft would give you a waste of 36ft?

Comment: sorry I should've mentioned that there are typically many pieces in an order, so we would use the 48ft to make 4 12ft pieces.

Comment: Ah thanks, that makes sense. Check my updated answer.